# Propagating errors from within a closure in a thread in Rust

Tags: multithreading, error-handling, rust

I want to propagate an error from a function called inside a closure inside a call to `thread::spawn`.

I've tried using a `JoinHandle` to capture the result of `thread::spawn`, but I get various errors doing that.

```
fn start_server(args) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    ...
    thread::spawn(move || {
        // I want to do this (put a ? after run_server)
        run_server(args)?;
        ...
    }
    ...        
});
```

```
fn run_server(args) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    ...
}
```

I get this message

```
|             run_server(args)?;
|             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
|
= help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `()`
= note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`
```

Comment: When asking for why some code does not compile, you should include code that can be actually given to the compiler to show the error. Preferably with a link to a copy in https://play.rust-lang.org/. In this case the detail that hides the devil is in those `...` after `run_server(args)?`. That is, you didn't post enough details to answer why the closure returns `()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I want to propagate an error from a function called inside a closure inside a call to thread::spawn

Since threads are running in parallel, throwing the error up from the thread scope is not making sense. Better approach will be error handling in the thread itself.

*So generally you should not propagate the error to the upper level above the thread.*

However you can throw your `error` that you get in your parallel `threads` after you `joined` them to your `main thread`. This way it will be pretty much like error propagation in synchronous.

Here is how you can manage it:

```rust
fn start_server() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let x = std::thread::spawn(move || -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        run_server()?;
        Ok(())
    });

    x.join().unwrap()?; // Now you can throw your error up because you joined your thread.
                        // ...
    Ok(())
}

fn run_server() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    Err(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "hello"))
}

fn main() {
    let x = start_server();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1331c9cd9b30e9d5e705468cef9ebea5)